# Why performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLEAR_FOCUS) always return false on editText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, accessibility

I want to clear the input focus from an editText in my accessibility service on a specific action.

I get the node with the input focus and try to clear it but performAction always return false:

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo root = getRootInActiveWindow();
AccessibilityNodeInfo focus = root.findFocus(AccessibilityNodeInfo.FOCUS_INPUT);

if(focus != null){

    focus.getText(); //return the text in my input
    focus.isFocusable(); //return true
    focus.isFocused(); // return true
    focus.getActions(); //Return the bitmask that contain the Action_clear_focus

    boolean sucess = focus.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLEAR_FOCUS);
    Log.v(TAG, "sucess = " + sucess); //Always return FALSE

}
```

Why the action cannot be performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you clear focus from a view, the view framework will attempt to place focus back on the first focusable element on the screen. So, if there is a single focusable element on screen, like an EditText, it will always have focus -- even if you call clearFocus().

Comment: And there is no way to manage if an element is focusable from accessibility service without any control on view elements? It's a service, not an application. Maybe I can change the focusable attribute to remove the focus from editText.

Comment: No, you can't modify view properties from an accessibility service.